# Magento 2: Bulk 301 rewrite imports

Tags: magento2, database, url-rewrite, 301-redirect, redirect-url

Read this great reference for creating a **csv** for import but this was for Magento 1 
and it states you only need store_id, **id_path,request_path, target_path, options** but these headers won't work for Magento 2.

In Magento 2 it looks like the **entity_id** is required and this would be painful indeed. Does anyone know what fields I need to import to get a massive amount of 301 rewrites into url_rewrites or a table that has paths and **entity_id** in it so I can cross reference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you can load your CSV file content then This is the way to import Bulk URL Rewrite:

Add below Code into script than run it.

```
// MAGENTO START
    include('../../../app/bootstrap.php');

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface;
    use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $scopeConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

    $_storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $dataProcessor = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor');

    $storeId = $_storeManager->getDefaultStoreView()->getStoreId();    

foreach($data as $key => $rec)
{   
    $urlRewrite = $objectManager->create(\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite::class);

    $urlRewrite->load(0);

    $model = $urlRewrite;
    $product['entity_type']      = $rec['entity_type'];
    $product['request_path']     = $rec['request_path'];
    $product['target_path']      = $rec['target_path'];
    $product['redirect_type']    = $rec['redirect_type'];
    $product['store_id']         = $rec['store_id'];

    $objectManager->get(\Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite::class)->validateRequestPath($product['request_path']);
    $model->setEntityType($product['entity_type'])
        ->setRequestPath($product['request_path'])
        ->setTargetPath($product['target_path'])
        ->setRedirectType($product['redirect_type'])
        ->setStoreId($product['store_id'])
        ->setDescription("Imported Urls");

    $model->save();
}

echo "Successfully Imported!";
```

> **$data** is the data from your csv or file. which should have same name column as above imported.
>
> **entity_id** is not required is you choose **entity_type** "**custom**"
>
> Set appropriate path to include bootstrap for "**include('../../../app/bootstrap.php');**", I have added my script in "**pub/script/vendor**", So I have applied path like this.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this by exporting the **url_rewrite** database table then added my custom redirects and imported via **phpMyadmin** and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution. 
Just create a csv with two columns

sku, product_websites

Then import it in smaller chunks of about 1000 products each. It should rewrite those product urls.

You can check if the url rewrite worked by going to marketing->url rewrites